# PHP My Admin + traefik - How to change default route?

Tags: php, docker, phpmyadmin, traefik

I know - this is a pretty specific question - but I'm having trouble finding a solution for this specific problem:

I would like to create a domain with the [traeffic-router](https://docs.traefik.io/) in the following format `db.mydomain.com/mydb1` and link to a [PHP my admin](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/) page.

However, I have problems with the **docker-MyAdmin tool** - it seems that you can't use a route like `'/mydb1'`.
Is there any trick how to do this?
I am at a loss after several hours of research tbh.

---

This is the docker-compose file I'm using for the myadmin configuration:

```
MyAdmin:
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=myDB
      - MYSQL_USER=xxx
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=xxx
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxx
    depends_on:
      - myDB
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - xx:80
    expose:
      - "xx"
    labels:
     - traefik.enable=true
     - traefik.http.routers.db.rule=Host(`db.mydomain.com`) && Path(`/mydb1`)
     - traefik.http.routers.db.entrypoints=web
     - traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https
     - traefik.http.routers.db.middlewares=redirect-to-https@docker
     - traefik.http.routers.db-secured.rule=Host(`db.mydomain.com`) && Path(`/mydb1`)
     - traefik.http.routers.db-secured.tls=true
     - traefik.http.routers.db-secured.tls.certresolver=myhttpchallenge
```

---

It looks like I'm getting an apache error from the myadmin web server - probably because the webserver waits for the `/index.php` instead of the `/mydb1` route.

[image: apache error]

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance.